# Investigating ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION issues

Tags: sonos

I'd like to know how you would recommend investigating transient `ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION` issues. I've experienced quite a lot of them this week end, so I went to the anacapa.trace logs on the speaker and got a lot of lines like those:

```
[Thu Jan  8 22:24:37 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Void (Radio Edit), share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:24:48 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Pirate Games, share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:24:59 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Boondocks, share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:25:12 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> Canceled subscription uuid:RINCON_B8E93729083201400_sub0000000074 to AVTransport svc (6 failures outstanding)
[Thu Jan  8 22:25:14 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Time Again (Radio Edit), share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:25:18 1970] <diag:trackplaymonitor,1> notifyEvent ignoring TPM_CHSNK_TRACK_BOUNDARY during 16 past buffered tracks: time: 685503:981882
[Thu Jan  8 22:26:07 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Eistee aus der Dose, share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:26:18 1970] <diag:chsrc,0> Transport error ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION for account type 40711, URI: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, friendly name: Outback, share/server: ..., path: x-sonosprog-http:....mp3?sid=159&flags=8224&sn=3, extra info: , http: -1, framer: mp3
[Thu Jan  8 22:26:33 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 2 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 10 secs: 1
[Thu Jan  8 22:26:48 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 3 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 20 secs: 1
[Thu Jan  8 22:27:13 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 4 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 40 secs: 1
[Thu Jan  8 22:27:58 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 5 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 80 secs: 1
[Thu Jan  8 22:29:23 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 6 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 160 secs: 1
[Thu Jan  8 22:32:08 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,1> 7 failure(s) sending event to 192.168.0.14:3400.  Retry in 160 secs: 0
[Thu Jan  8 22:32:08 1970] <diag:upnpeventing,0> Terminated subscription #69 for 192.168.0.14:3400
```

I searched for service-side logs and couldn't find any issue, and most of the time I couldn't even find a log line for a `getMediaURI` call for those tracks, so for some reason they don't make it to the service code.

Is there a way to get more useful client logs (like the request that was made to the service and the response it got)? Or what information can I extract from the current logs (`ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION` could mean a lot of things)? I'm a bit at a loss out there, especially since those errors seem to be transient and I can't correlate them with service-side errors...

Answer (score 0):

Generally ERROR_LOST_CONNECTION implies an inability to reach the server; generally these are caused by network connectivity issues.  In this case the error is coming from the transport layer which implies that we are failing to reach the server on the `getMediaUri` request.

You can increase the logging that you see in the anacapa.trace file by hitting the following urls:
http://`IP_address_of_ZonePlayer`:1400/diaglevel?module=chsrc&level=5
http://`IP_address_of_ZonePlayer`:1400/diaglevel?module=soap&level=5
http://`IP_address_of_ZonePlayer`:1400/diaglevel?module=sonoscp&level=5

This will give more you more information about what is happening during the failures in the logs.

Another approach to see what you want to is to use a switch that has port mirroring as that will allow you to see both incoming and out going traffic in full.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'll increase the diagnostic level and try to find more information there the next time I hit this issue.

Comment: Hey Keith, I've just reproed the issue with heightened diagnostic levels but there's nothing interesting in http://{speakerIP}:1400/status/opt/log/anacapa.trace. Is there another location where I could find relevant logs (like service requests/responses details)?

Comment: No that is the main source.  That would imply that messages are not getting back to the player.  I would suggest using Wireshark to take a look at the traffic using a switch with port mirroring as mentioned above as your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I have started doing that indeed, but these kind of issues are never easy to debug...